# How to make this image lightbox work for both horizontal and vertical images?

Tags: html, css

I need to create an image lightbox. I basically started from this example from w3school, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

However, it doesn't work for portrait oriented images. Eg. a landscape image is 1200x800 and a portrait can be 800x1200.

I need the images to resize responsive and work for both horizontal and vertical images.
It needs to work for all modern browsers, ios, android and also IE11.

you'll see I've added "max-width: 1200px;" to lightbox-content, which does the trick for horizontal images... but since a vertical image is 800 wide, it enlarges and the height exceeds.

```
<div class="lightbox">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeLightbox()">&times;</span>
    <div class="lightboxTitle">My Title</div>
    <div class="lightbox-content">
        <div class="slide"><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>

        <!-- Next/previous controls -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
</div>


/* The Modal (background) */
.lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999999;
    padding-top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* Modal Content */
.lightbox-content {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.lightboxTitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #FF8511;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.slide {
    display: none;
}

.slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
   .prev:hover,
   .next:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   color: #FF8511;
}
```

Comment: Use both max-width and max-height properties. This will make sure that the image is contained irrespective of the varying aspect ratios.

Comment: this doesn't work and will not make the image responsive for small screens.. The image still comes outside of the bounds of lightbox-content in that case

Comment: I use vh and vw for such scenarios. I make the max-height 80vh and max-width 80vw and it keeps a gap of 10vh and 10vw on either side of the image. Nothing to do with changing screen sizes as vh and vw will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of my past projects. I solved it with this js library https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/,

It allows you to process the images after they are loaded, and you can then assign a css class to it according to the aspect ratio.

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // images have loaded
  // check image height/width > 1, portrait
  // check image heidht/width <= 1, square or landscape
  // assign different classes for each case to handle
});
```

css:

```
.img-container {
  //do whatever you need on the container

}

// keep the image classes like this
.img-container img.portrait {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.img-container img.landscape {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: yes, I've considered processing the images using javascript.. but was hoping for a CSS only solution